# Java Listener reference prevents garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am worried that I might end up with a lot of "undead" Objects inside my Listener List
that still get notified even though they could simply be removed.

Assume the following classes:

This is my ListView, a UI component where I use the `addItem` method to populate the list with objects.
After a while I might call `clear` to remove every Item in the List:

```
//Displays some Model objects
ListView
{
    //Creates a new Cell via createCell and adds the Cell to the ItemList
    public void addItem(MyModelObject obj) { ... }
    //Simply cleares the ItemList
    public void clear() { ... }

    ...

    //Creates a new Cell to be added to the ListView
    private ListCell createCell(MyModelObject obj)
    {
        //Create the Controller for the Cell and return the Cell
        return new ListCellController(obj).getCellUI();
    }
}
```

This is the ListCellController seen in the `createCell` method above. It holds the reference to a Model Object and is responsible for setting the correct contents in the ListCell it controls.
The Controller sets itself as a Listener in the Model Object:

```
//Handles the Content that is displayed in a ListCell
ListCellController implements MyModelObjectListener
{
    private final ListCell _ui = ...

    public ListCellController(MyModelObject obj)
    {
        obj.addListener(this); //Get informed if Model Object changes
        _ui.setText(obj.getName()); //Control what is displayed in the Cell
    }

    //Returns the UI Object that is controlled by this Controller
    public ListCell getCellUI() { return _ui; }

    ...
}
```

This is the Model Object, it does some stuff and occasionally notifies its listeners if it changed.

```
//My Model Object that informs listeners if it changed
MyModelObject
{
    private List<MyModelObjectListener _listeners = ...;

    ...
    public void addListener(MyModelObjectListener listener) { ... }
}
```

Now, what happens if I add some Items to the ListView and then clear it? The ListView never holds any references to Controller objects, only to ListCells. If the ListView is cleared, all the references to ListCells are discarded.

The ListCells do not know if they are currently displayed or already discarded and of course the Controller cannot know either.

I assume, that now, even though the ListView is empty, the Model Object still holds the references to the Controllers in the `_listeners` List. Because of that, the Controllers are not garbage-collected and thus, the ListCells are neither.

Does that mean that, if I add and remove a lot of Items from my ListView I will end up with a huge List of Listeners? How can I avoid this If I do not know if a ListCell is displayed or not?

**TL;DR:
Will my `_listeners` List prevent garbage-collection of Controllers and ListCells?**

Comment: Circular references do not cause a problem for Java GC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding well what is your problem, but for what I know about garbage collection, even if two object refer to each other, if none of them is referenced in runtime, they will be deleted anyway.

So, if your problem is about this, if you have at least one listener referenced in runtime, it will not be garbage collected, therefore, you would have to remove it manually.

I hope I could be of any help.